# Finding sum of values generated from a for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Hi totally new and struggling with a likely simple prob.
I have a for-loop creating values and printing the running total as they're generated. 
I need to find a way to print the sum of those running totals (in the case below: 3 + 33 + 333) I have a feeling a nested loop is an option but not sure where it'd go. Am I close?  (Thanks)

Here is my code thus far:

```
def nSum(num):
    #calculating values for the variable (num) to the p power:
    p = 0
    newValue = 0
    for i in range(num):
        currentVal = num * 10**p
        p = p+1
    #running total of the curent values:
        newValue = currentVal + newValue
        print(newValue)
    return newValue

print(nSum(3)) #Want nSum to be total of all the newValues from the loop
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
def nSum(num):
    #calculating values for the variable (num) to the p power:
    p = 0
    newValue = 0 
    total_value=0 #new variable
    for i in range(num):
        currentVal = num * 10**p
        p = p+1
    #running total of the curent values:
        newValue = currentVal + newValue
        print(newValue)
        total_value+=newValue #new line
    return total_value

print(nSum(3)) #Want nSum to be total of all the newValues from the loop
```

Or you can do it without using `p` variable.You can do it only using `i` variable.Like :

```
def nSum(num):
    #calculating values for the variable (num) to the p power:
    newValue = 0
    total_value=0
    for i in range(num):
        currentVal = num * 10**i
    #running total of the curent values:
        newValue = currentVal + newValue
        print(newValue)
        total_value+=newValue
    return total_value

print(nSum(3)) #Want nSum to be total of all the newValues from the loop
```

Comment: huh? Why are you using `p = 0`, `p += 1`? Just use `i`.

Comment: I know this, but i tried to make my answer as same as question. It will be more helpful for him to get my answer.

Comment: @FHTMitchell I have updated my answer as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Did you really edit your answer to mirror mine?  What's the point?

Comment: We have answered almost at the same time. And then I have updated my answer as FHTMitchell suggested. That's it. The idea was same, may be that's why there is similarity between our answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep track of the intermediate values:

```
def nSum(num):
    #calculating values for the variable (num) to the p power:
    values = []
    for p in range(num):
        currentVal = num * 10**p
        #running total of the curent values:
        newValue = currentVal + (values[-1] if values else 0)
        values.append(newValue)

    return values

print(sum(nSum(3))) #Want nSum to be total of all the newValues from the loop
```

If you don't care about them, you can drop the list and just use an accumulator:

```
def nSum(num):
    #calculating values for the variable (num) to the p power:
    total = 0
    new_value = 0
    for p in range(num):
        currentVal = num * 10**p
        #running total of the curent values:
        new_value += currentVal
        total += new_value

    return total

print(nSum(3))
```

P.S. You don't need to define and increment `p` -- you can just use your (currently unused) variable `i` -- which is incremented automatically by `range`.